# AWS SNS topic initial value

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for something I dubbed 'state' topics.
Once a subscriber successfully subscribed it will receive the current value of a topic: the current/actual state.
After that the subscriber will receive updates of the topic as usual.

Ideas?

A two phase approach might work:
Topic A to transport the actual state change from an instance to farm level. A lambda could subscribe to this topic and persist the state.
Another topic B is used to transport from farm level to other interested parties.
Question remains: can I do a single 'subscription accepted' call and provide current state?

Comment: You will need more than just SNS. You need to store the state in some stateful store, and you need to write the parts that notify the subscriber upon subscription and upon state change. Technologies that come to mind are S3, CloudWatch, SNS and perhaps Lambda to glue the subscription part together.

Comment: Yes, I understand the persistence part. I would rather not do additional calls to the subscriber (this induces several timing scenarios that may cause issues). This would work, but not be robust enough, I think.